# Maximiser of $W_1(\mu, \nu)$ can be changed outside of $\text{conv}(\text{supp}(\mu) \cap \text{supp}(\nu))$ (under additional assumptions)

Tags: measure-theory, optimization, convex-optimization, optimal-transport, wasserstein

> Let $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ be a [reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space) Banach space and $\mathbb{P}_n$, $\mathbb{P}_r$ be measures on $X$.
> Let the support of $\mathbb{P}_r$, $M := \text{supp}(\mathbb{P}_r)$ be a [weakly compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology) set and $$P_M \colon D \to M, \qquad x \mapsto \text{argmin}_{y \in M} \| x - y \|$$ be the projection onto $M$ and $D \subset X$ the set of points for which the projection is unique (and thus the map $P_M$ is well-defined).
> Assume further that $\mathbb{P}_n(D) = 1$ and [$(P_M)_{\#} \mathbb{P}_n = \mathbb{P}_r$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure).

*(As $M$ is weakly compact, the projection always exists, but it need not be unique, as $M$ need not be convex.)*

The [Wasserstein-1 distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Dual_representation_of_W1) for measures is
$$
W_1(\mathbb{P}_r, \mathbb{P}_n)
= \sup_{f \in 1\text{-Lip}} \int_{X} f(x) \; \text{d}(\mathbb{P}_n - \mathbb{P}_r)(x),
$$
where $1$-Lip denotes the set of [1-Lipschitz-continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) functions $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$.

Remark 2 in the paper [Adversarial Regularizers in Inverse Problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11572) by Lunz et al. states that the maximiser $f$ in the above formula is not unique: it can be changed to an arbitrary 1-Lipschitz function outside of $\text{conv}(\text{supp}(\mathbb{P}_r) \cap \text{supp}(\mathbb{P}_n))$.

**But the statement is wrong (see below) but does somebody know what could be meant instead? If we replace the $\cap$ by a $\cup$ do we even need the convex hull anymore?**

**Counterexample (thanks to @MaoWao)**

But taking $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{P}_r := \delta_0$ we have $M = \text{supp}(\mathbb{P}_r) = \{ 0 \}$, which is weakly compact and the projection is
$$
P_M \colon \mathbb{R} \to \{ 0 \}, \qquad
x \mapsto 0.
$$
Choosing $\mathbb{P}_n := \delta_1$, we have $\text{supp}(\mathbb{P}_n) \cap \text{supp}(\mathbb{P}_r) = \emptyset$.
Furthermore, for any measurable set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\mathbb{P}_n(P_M^{-1}(A))
= \begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}_n(\emptyset) = 0, & \text{if } 0 \notin A, \\
\mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{R}) = 1,& \text{if } 0 \in A.
\end{cases}
= \mathbb{P}_r(A),
$$
so $(P_M)_{\#} \mathbb{P}_n = \mathbb{P}_r$.
But
$$
W_1(\mathbb{P}_r, \mathbb{P}_n)
= \sup_{f \in 1\text{-Lip}} f(1) - f(0) 
= 1
$$
for e.g. $f(x) = x$.
But if we are allowed to change $f$ to on the complement of $\emptyset$, that is, anywhere, (such that it remains 1-Lipschitz) we can instead consider $\tilde{f}(x) = - x$, for which the objective function takes the value $- 1 \ne 1$.

Comment: That's probably a typo. If $\mu=\delta_a$ and $\nu=\delta_b$ with $a\neq b$, then the convex hull of the intersection of the supports of $\mu$ and $\nu$ is empty, yet it is certainly not true that $f(a)-f(b)$ has the same value for all $1$-Lipschitz functions $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted the author and they said it is supposed to instead be
$$
\text{conv}(\text{supp}(\mathbb{P}_r) \color{red}{\cup} \text{supp}(\mathbb{P}_n)).
$$
For the counterexample this then means that we can alter $f$ to an 1-Lipschitz function outside of $\text{conv}(\{ 0 \} \cup \{ 1 \}) = [0, 1]$, which will not change $f(1) - f(0)$, so the counterexample is not a counterexample to the corrected statement.